# curious luatex warning checksum mismatch in font txr.vf ignored

Tags: luatex, luaotfload

The warning mentioned in the title occurs only if luaotfload is loaded. The `txr.vf` + `txr.tfm` files are OK: other TeX engines or dvips etc. don't have problem, `tftopl` and `vftovp` show that the checksum is the same, the clean new TeXlive 2013 or 2014 pretest distribution is used.

here is a minimal file:

```
\input luaotfload.sty
\font\f=txr \f a\end
```

Process it by `luatex`. The terminal or log says:

```
checksum mismatch in font txr.vf ignored  [1{/.../tl2013/texmf-var/fonts/m
ap/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] ){/.../tl2013/texmf-dist/fonts/enc/dvips/bas
e/8r.enc}</.../tl2013/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb>
</.../tl2013/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/urw/times/utmr8a.pfb>
Output written on pok.pdf (1 page, 12634 bytes).
Transcript written on pok.log.
```

The ``more minimal'' file is:

```
\input luafonts
\font\f=txr \f a\end
```

The file `luafonts.tex` does the same as `luaotfload.sty`, it means that it reinstalls the `\font` primitive in order to the OTF fonts can be loaded. The only difference is that `luafonts.tex` doesn't input next 42 external files.

If we comment out the line `\input luaotfload.sty` or `luafonts` then the curious warning doesn't appear. The `txr` font is normal `tfm+vf` font, no OTF. Other fonts are without this problem. It seems that the warning is a bug in luaotfload code. Is it true?

Comment: The checksum is compared when a pair `<name>.tfm` and `<name>.vf` is found, which should ensure they were both produced by the same run of `vptovf` (or other program). In the case where `<name>` is `txr`, the checksum is 32212676346 (octal) for both, so my feeling is that `luaotfload` does the wrong comparison.

Comment: The problem has been discussed some time ago http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.tex.live/30992 but imho never really been investigated (it doesn't make much sense to use such fonts with lualatex). You could open a bug report at `https://github.com/lualatex/luaotfload/issues?state=open`

Comment: Also the checksum for the mapped fonts coincide, in my TeX distribution, but with `luafonts` the warning appears nonetheless. I tried recreating the `.vf` and `.tfm` files after removing the checksum information in the `.vpl` file. The recreated files show the same information as before, because the checksums are taken from the referenced fonts. But the warning remains.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: (it doesn't make much sense to use such fonts with lualatex) -- with lua*la*tex may be but the font is set as default for math in csplain format when Times-like font family is selected. I.e. it is used with luatex. Regardles of the usage of this font it is not good new that the TeX engine we are using includes a bug.

Comment: I only wanted to explain why nobody really pressed to solve the problem: is only a (harmless) message you don't get often. And you should be aware that luatex and luaotfload certainly contains more (and more serious) bugs. The best you can do is to report them so that they can be solved.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Care to write an answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem has been discussed some time ago http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.tex.live/30992 but imho never really been investigated (it doesn't make much sense to use such fonts with lualatex and so there is not much pressure in resolving a rather harmless warning).

You could open a bug report at https://github.com/lualatex/luaotfload/issues?state=open

Comment: [Already reported](https://github.com/lualatex/luaotfload/issues/223)