# checksum mismatch in font futr8t.vf ignored

Tags: luatex, fourier

With this `MWE` :

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\RequirePackage{fontspec}
\usefonttheme{serif}
\RequirePackage{lmodern}
\RequirePackage{fourier}

\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty

\RequirePackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{french}

\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usecolortheme{wolverine}

\title{\textbf{\textsc{La Boîte à Questions}}}
\author{Mathématiques}
\date{6$^{e}$}
\institute{2014 -- 2015}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[plain]
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

I have this error messages because of a problem between `lualatex` and `fourier` :

```
checksum mismatch in font futr8t.vf ignored 
checksum mismatch in font futbc8t.vf ignored 
checksum mismatch in font futr8t.vf ignored 
...
```

I use texlive 2013, but I saw that the problem exits in 2010, but no solution.

Any idea ?

Comment: Ignore the ignored mismatch. ;-) I checked other instances and always found the checksums actually match.

Comment: Looks like http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/179543/15925, which is not really resolved.

Comment: @egreg and andrew : thank you, I'll will ignore that.